# Fiber tape changer missing on lsscsi

Tags: server, scsi

I'm configuring a server with `Bacula` to manipulate backups on a Dell TL4000 connected to the server via Fiber.

During the configuration of the `Bacula Director` I've accessed the `bconsole` to see if the configurations was being applied. Once I've exited the console, the `lsscsi` stopped showing the `mediumx` (changer) on the list. It shows the two drives, but nothing about the changer and, before entering the console it showed the changer.

I've tried restarting the `TL` and using `rescan-scsi-bus`, but nothing too.
Anyone have a clue about this?

I'm using `Ubuntu Server 16.04.3`, and installed `Bacula` via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that, on the Library Type configuration on the `TL` are two options: Random and Sequential. I've changed it to sequential, thinking that it was going to force the Library to use the tapes in the numbered order. This option make the changer disappear on the server. I tested change this option back and forth and everytime it is on Sequential the changer disappear.